# Rotate render texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to output camera's view into a render texture but unfortunately the render texture is rotated 180 degrees. Why and how do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class RenderCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public RenderTexture renderTexture;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotIntoRenderTexture(renderTexture);
        AsyncGPUReadback.Request(renderTexture, 0, TextureFormat.RGBA32, ReadbackCompleted);
    }

    void ReadbackCompleted(AsyncGPUReadbackRequest request)
    {
        // Render texture no longer needed, it has been read back.
        //DestroyImmediate(renderTexture);

        using (var imageBytes = request.GetData<byte>())
        {
            // do something with the pixel data.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried rotating the render texture in the scene?

Comment: how does one rotate it? That is my question.

Comment: Click on the render texture plane. From the inspector, change the Rotation.  You will be changing a single component, most like Z, whichever axis points through the plane.